# How to I display why some tests where skipped while using py.test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am using `skipIf()` from `unittest` for skipping tests in certain conditions.

```
@unittest.skipIf(condition), "this is why I skipped them!")
```

How do I tell `py.test` to display skipping conditions?

I know that for unittest I need to enable the verbose mode (`-v`) but the same parameter added to py.test increase the verbosity by still does not display the skip reasons.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

When you run py.test, you can pass `-rsx` to report skipped tests.

From `py.test --help`:

```
-r chars            show extra test summary info as specified by chars
                    (f)ailed, (E)error, (s)skipped, (x)failed, (X)passed.
```

Also see this part of the documentation about skipping: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html

Answer (score 33):

**Short answer:**

```
pytest -rs
```

This will show extra information of skipped tests.

**Detailed answer:**

To complement @ToddWilson's answer, the following chars have been added: `p` and `P` ([2.9.0](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/changelog.html#id1184)), `a` ([4.1.0](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/changelog.html#pytest-4-1-0-2019-01-05)) and `A` ([4.5.0](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/changelog.html#pytest-4-5-0-2019-05-11)). The detailed information about skipped and xfailed tests is not shown by default in order to avoid cluttering the output. You can use the [`-r`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html) flag among with the following chars:

- (`f`)ailed
- (`E`)rror
- (`s`)kipped
- (`x`)failed
- (`X`)passed
- (`p`)assed
- (`P`)assed with output
- (`a`)ll except passed (p/P)
- (`A`)ll.

Warnings are enabled by default, and the default value is `fE`.