# How to report reasons for skipped tests when running pytest with --collect-only?

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest

When running pytest, I understand how to [report the skip reasons when actually executing tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495950/how-to-i-display-why-some-tests-where-skipped-while-using-py-test), but how can I report the skip reasons when running pytest with the `--collect-only` option?  Running pytest with `--collect-only -rsx` does not report the reasons for skipping the tests.  I'm using pytest version 6.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, there is an open item on the [pytest-dev github](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1509) for this or a similar kind of issue.

For now, if feasible, you could add documentation in your skipped tests (using doc strings) so that the reasons would be displayed with verbose runs of --collect-only
Here is the workaround from another thread of the same github [workaround](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/4582)

```
@pytest.mark.skip(reason="skipped test")
def test_2():
    """this is skipped as the function does not work as of now"""
    pass

Console:
pytest -v -s file.py --collect-only 

Result:
collected 5 items                                                                                                                                                                         

<Module tone.py>
<Function test_2>
this is skipped as the function does not work as of now
<Function test_3>
<Function test_4>
<Function test_5>
<Function test_6>
```